# How did the felines get to America?

Tags: evolution, zoology, feline, migration

I don't know if the felines got originated on America or on Africa, but I do know there are species of cat in America and Africa that belong to the same family and genus (Felidae & Panthera).

How did the evolution of these animals beat the vastness of the ocean? The same way as *Homo sapiens*? Or did they coexisted before Pangea split?

Comment: There are species of felines native to Eurasia, so it's not as though there is a great gap, either geographically or genetically.

Answer (score 30):

**Short answer**
It is believed that low water levels occurring several times during the last ten million years facilitated migration and divergent evolution of the felids. The North-American ocelot, lynx, puma, leopard cat, and domestic cat are believed to have evolved from a common ancestor that crossed the Bering land bridge between 5 to 9 million years ago from Eurasia. Note that [Pangea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea) broke apart 175 million years ago, way before the [Age of Mammals](http://www.bobpickett.org/evolution_of_mammals.htm) even started, 65 million years ago.

**Background**
It is believed that modern felids arose in **Asia** with the divergence of the [genus *Panthera*](https://www.wildcatfamily.com/panthera-lineage/) 10.8 million years ago (Mya) and the [bay cat lineage](https://www.wildcatfamily.com/bay-cat-lineage/) 9.4 Mya. These dates correspond to the low sea levels that occurred during the late Miocene (Fig. 1). Between 8.5 to 5.6 Mya a progenitor of the caracal lineage arrived in **Africa**. The common ancestor to five felid lineages (ocelot, lynx, puma, leopard cat, and domestic cat) migrated across the Bering land bridge to **North America**, referred to as the New World migration. This period is also believed to have facilitated migrations of the **Eurasian** carnivores (ursid, procyonid, mustelid, and saber-toothed felids) to **North America**.

Additional Pliocene/Pleistocene migrations paved the way for the differentiation of the cheetah, originating from the **North American** puma and migrating to central **Asia** and **Africa**. Reversely, **Asian** Panthera species spread into **America** (jaguar, lion) and subsequently into Africa (lion and leopard).

[image: felids]
<sup>Fig. 1. Global migrations of felids. source: [Johnson *et al*., (2006)](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/311/5757/73.full.pdf)</sup>

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Johnson *et al*., *Science* (2006); **311**: 73-7](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/311/5757/73.full.pdf)</sub>

Comment: I thought modern domestic cats were originally bred from wild cats of Egypt and the Middle East.